# Using Oracle function Based index in Composite Information Studio

Tags: oracle11g, composite

I am developing in Cisco Information Server using the client Cisco Information Studio.

Initially my requirement was to create function based index in Composite itself something similar to

```
create index index_name on table(user_defined_function/procedure)
```

But it seems that it wont be possible to create an index in composite server.

So now what I would like to do is create a function based index in the Oracle DB and then use the same function in Composite Views.

I created the function and then an index on that function in my Oracle DB. Then I introspected the Db to Composite. All the tables can in but no functions or indexes were introspected. I tried to call the function as well in Composite views but am getting the error that the function does not exist.

Can someone help me out with some suggestion on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

So far, CIS does not support creating or introspecting function based index from any data source.

Best shot: You can define the function based index at DB level. If your SQL query fetching the data is optimized, composite will push the entire query to the database. Given the database has the index set, it will respond faster to composite. To investigate if your entire query is getting pushed down to the database, you can run it and investigate in "Manager" tab -> Requests -> select your query -> "Show Query Plan" Button.

If the query you are running is across databases and your function (for indexing) needs access to more than 1 database: Please wait for Cisco to implement function based index ( I don't see how that would work though).